# prevent column to expand when parent is width 100%

Tags: html, css

I have a table where I specify width:100% but I don't want to expand one particular column(image column) to expand. It it possible?

Sample example:

```css
body {}

img.consoleIcon,
img.ConsoleIconColumnHeader {
  width: 17px !important;
  height: 17px !important;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

table td,
table th {
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Facebook</th>
    <th>Twitter</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>Shubh</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td>
      <a>
        <img title="FB" class="consoleIcon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/124/124010.svg">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Now the above is simple example of a table without any width specified to it, now I go ahead & apply style width:100% but I don't want the image column(e.g Facebook) to expand.

```css
body{
 
}
img.consoleIcon, img.ConsoleIconColumnHeader {
    width: 17px !important;
    height: 17px !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

table td, table th{
      
  border:1px solid #d0d0d0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
<thead>
  <th>Name</th>
  <th>Age</th>
  <th>Facebook</th>
  <th>Twitter</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <td>Shubh</td>
  <td>33</td>
  <td>
    <a>
      <img title="FB" class="consoleIcon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/124/124010.svg">
                </a>
  </td>
  <td></td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You could use a fixed width

Comment: @spidyx : fixed width for icon columns? If yes, then I tried that. It still expands.

Comment: I post a snippet in answer below

Answer (score 2):

You can set the width on the `td` element.
Here I define an `icon-cell` class, on the `td` element, and I am setting a width in CSS :

```css
img.consoleIcon, img.ConsoleIconColumnHeader {
    width: 17px !important;
    height: 17px !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
table td, table th {          
  border: 1px solid #d0d0d0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
}
.icon-cell {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%">
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Age</th>
    <th>Facebook</th>
    <th>Twitter</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <td>Shubh</td>
    <td>33</td>
    <td class="icon-cell">
      <a>
        <img title="FB" class="consoleIcon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/124/124010.svg">
      </a>
    </td>
    <td></td>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

By applying the fixed width for table columns solved this problem.

Hope it is useful to you.

Here is my Code

```
<table style="width:100%">
<thead>
  <th style="width:35%;">Name</th>
  <th style="width:30%;">Age</th>
  <th style="width:5%;">Facebook</th>
  <th style="width:30%;">Twitter</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
  <td>Shubh</td>
  <td>33</td>
  <td>
    <a>
      <img title="FB" class="consoleIcon" src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/svg/124/124010.svg">
                </a>
  </td>
  <td></td>
</tbody>
</table>
```

In CSS

```
body{

}
img.consoleIcon, img.ConsoleIconColumnHeader {
    width: 17px !important;
    height: 17px !important;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

table td, table th{

  border:1px solid #d0d0d0;
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse !important;
}
```

Here is the Working Fiddle

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/1bn5ke9s/][1]
```